# My brother is 4 times as old as I am. Six years from now, he will be twice as old as I will be. How old is my brother now?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

My brother is 4 times as old as I am. Six years from now, he will be twice as old as I will be. How old is my brother now?

I thought the answer was 18, but that was incorrect. I had x=4y and 6+2y=x. I'm not sure how to set this up.

Comment: Please explain what $x$ and $y$ represent.

Comment: 4x=y, 2(x+6)=y+6

Comment: Using your $x$ and $y$, how old will you be in 6 years?  How old will your brother be in 6 years?

Comment: It shouldn't be $6 + 2y = x$  That is your brother now is twice as old as you are now plus 6 years.  You want your brother in six years  $x+6$ will be twice as old as you will be in six years.  You in six years is $y + 6$ and twice that is $2(y+6)$.  So $(x+6) = 2(y+6)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple.
So:

My age is $M$,
Bro's age is $B$.
$2M+12=B+6$

You also have another piece of information:  $\;4M=B.$

Substitute that into the equation as if it was a simultaneous equation question:

$$2M+12=4M+6,$$
$$12=2M+6,$$
$$M=3.$$

Your age is 3;
Your brother's age is 12.

Answer (score 0):

$m$=age of me

$b$=age of brother

$$4m=b$$
For every $1$ year you spent, he spent $4$ years.

To make the year value equal, one needs to multiply the number of years you spent ($m$) by $4$.

$$2(4m+6)=b$$

After $6$ years, your original age of $4m$ becomes $4m+6$.

Your brother is now twice as old as you.

Now, for every $1$ year you spent, he spent $2$ years.

To make the year value equal, one needs to multiply the number of years you spent ($4m+6)$ by $2$.

Comment: I'm getting b=6 and m=1.5. So 4m+6=12. So he will be 12?

Comment: @ddswsd Check. $$4(1.5)=6 \implies 6=6$$ $$2(4(1.5)+6)=6 \implies 2(12)=6$$

This is incorrect because $$24\ne 6$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the age of the brother and $I$ be the age of you.

We have given from the problem that right now, your brother is four times older than you. This is the same as saying: $$B=4I$$

It goes on to say that in $6$ years, he will be twice the age as you. This can be represented as:
$$B+6 = 2(I+6)$$

We now have two equations in two unknowns. We can solve for the variables using some basic algebra techniques. Remember the question originally asks for the value of $B$

The easiest way would be to plug in $B=4I$ to the bottom equation to get: $$4I+6=2(I+6)$$

Then just solve for $I$ to get your current age, then plug that in to the first equation to arrive at the answer.

Comment: There is no explanation.

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: I'll undo my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ = me now

$b$ = brother now

$x + 6$ = me in six years

$b+ 6$ = brother in six years.

So....

$b = 4x$

$b + 6 = 2(x +6)$.

Two linear independent equations with two unknown variables.  Solve them.  It's straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your first equation: $x=4y$.

From this, $x$ is your brother's age now, and $y$ is your age now.

In six years, your age will be $y+6$ and your brother's age will be $x+6$.

Six years from now, if your brother will be twice as old as you will be, then $2(y+6) = x+6$.

Can you take it from here?

Spoiler:

> You're solving for $x$ so substitute $y=x/4$ in the second equation:
>  $$2((x/4)+6)=x+6$$
>  Solving for $x$ gives $x=12$.
>  You can check by seeing that if $x=12$ then $y=3$. Six years from now, $x=18$, and $y=9$.

Comment: This is essentially what I did, but 18 is not the correct answer for the brothers age. It makes sense though.

Comment: @ddswsd $18$ isn't the correct answer. $18$ is the age of the brother *after $6$ years*

Comment: So he is 12 years old now!

Answer (score 0):

If you represent x, and your brother is 4 times your age, he would be 4*x, or 4x. In 6 years, he will be twice as old, so you become x+6, and your brother is 4x+6, but he is twice as old as you, so if you were to divide your brothers current age by half, it would be x+6=4x+6/2, which you then multiply both sides by 2, to cancel out the divide by two. Its then 2x+12=4x+6, which should be easy enough to solve, and x=3 But thats not what the question is asking. Its asking for your brothers age, but since we know that hes 3, then his brother is currently **12**.

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164